# How to show that a function that "jumps up" is invertible using calculus methods?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose we have the function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
        x,&\text{ if }x\geq0\\
        x^3-1,&\text{ if }x<0
\end{cases}
$$

How can we show that this function is invertible using calculus methods? For a function that did not "jump up" the proof would be as simple as just showing the derivative was always positive hence the function is increasing and one-to-one but for this sort of function it seems that an extra statement is needed. How to go about writing the proof for this?

Comment: Both functions are one-to-one on their respective domains, so inverses locally exist. Write the expression for each piece's derivative

Comment: The function is increasing for $x<0$ and for $x\geq 0$. So, to verify that the function is increasing you just have to verify that for $x\leq 0 \leq y$ we have $f(x)\leq f(y)$ with equality only if $x=y$. Another approach could be to find an inverse $g: Im(f) \to \mathbb{R}$ - done below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply write its inverse $g:(-\infty,-1)\cup [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ (note that $(-\infty,-1)\cup [0,\infty) =$ Im$(f)$):

$$
g(y) = \begin{cases}
        y,&\text{ if }y\geq0\\
        (y+1)^{1/3},&\text{ if }y<-1
\end{cases}
$$

If $x\geq 0$:
$g(f(x)) = g(x) = x$

If $x<0$:
$g(f(x)) = g(x^3-1) = ((x^3-1)+1)^{1/3} = x$

If $y\geq 0$:
$f(g(y)) = f(y) = y$

If $y<1$:

$f(g(y)) = f((y+1)^{1/3})$, since in this case $(y+1)^{1/3}<0$, we have $f((y+1)^{1/3})=((y+1)^{1/3})^3-1 = y$

So that $g$ is an inverse for $f$.

Comment: @DavidK you are 100% right. I just edited it to fix the problem. Since the function "jumps", the domain of the inverse should not be considered to be the whole $\mathbb{R}$ but only $Im(f) = (-\infty,-1)\cup[0,\infty)$. Thank you very much.